# Get album year for item in iPod library?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

Trying the following code:

```
// Per albums
MPMediaQuery *albumsQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
NSArray *collections = [albumsQuery collections];

for (MPMediaItemCollection *collection in collections)
{
    NSDate *collectionReleaseDate = [collection valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyReleaseDate];
    NSLog(@"collection release date: %@", collectionReleaseDate);

    MPMediaItem *representativeItem = [collection representativeItem];
    NSDate *representativeItemReleaseDate = [representativeItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyReleaseDate];
    NSLog(@"representativeItem release date: %@", representativeItemReleaseDate);
}

// Just per item
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSArray *items = [query items];

for (MPMediaItem *item in items)
{
    NSDate *date = [item valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyReleaseDate];
    NSLog(@"release date: %@", date);
}
```

In all cases I get nil's for NSDates...
But in the iPod library I can see dates, so the information must be available.
What is the correct way to obtain it?

Comment: The release date is only accessible using iOS 4 or above. What is your target version?

Comment: Using iOS SDK 4.2, deployment target = iOS 4.0, testing on iPad with 4.2.1 and iPod 2nd gen with 4.2.1 ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, I think I've figured it out. I was thinking that 'Year' column in iTunes corresponds to MPMediaItemPropertyReleaseDate in API - but it's wrong. My items actually weren't having release date info.

I also found how to obtain 'Year' information (which I needed), but unfortunately in undocumented way:

```
MPMediaItem *item = ...;
NSNumber *yearNumber = [item valueForProperty:@"year"];
if (yearNumber && [yearNumber isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
{
    int year = [yearNumber intValue];
    if (year != 0)
    {
        // do something with year
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andy Works on iOS 6.0 for me.

Comment: @soheilpro do you test on 6.0 or 6.1?

Comment: @Andy 6.0. Have you tested it on 6.1?

Comment: @soheilpro yeah strange, also used 6.0 and it didn't work for me. :/

Comment: Wow this is awesome! Works on ios 9.0.2. I don't know why Apple doesn't provide that kind of information.

Comment: Thanks for that! works on iOS 9.3.2 too, just checked.