# getting ID3 tag info from songs in iPhone's music library

Tags: ios, objective-c, id3, mpmediaitem

I'm trying to fetch the "year" property of songs in my iPhone's music library.
I realized that this property is an ID3 property and not a MPMediaItem property, so I need to make a connection between MPMediaItem (which I can access) and the song's ID3 tags.
I tried to use MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL to get the song's URL and then read the ID3 properties from the file itself, but the app crashes when I use NSURLWithString. string is "ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=3444682451933208387" for example (that's MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL value)
what am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Not very clean but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862646/get-album-year-for-item-in-ipod-library ?

Comment: Fantastic! works also in ios 10